# Chrome changes style.filter syntax

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

Check this fiddle out:

```js
var element = document.getElementById("div");
console.log(element.style.filter);
```

```html
<div style = 'filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px black); width: 50px; height: 50px; background: red' id='div'></div>
```

Firefox will output:

```
drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px black)
```

that is ok.

Chrome will output:

```
drop-shadow(black 0px 0px 5px)
```

moving the `color` parameter (`black`) at first place making hard to parse it on multi browsers...
Does anyone know why and if there is a way to standardize it?

Comment: Why do you want to parse it?

Comment: @Satpal: to make a long story short, I'm making an HTML5 edirtor and I want to give the user the option to visually edit element filters

Comment: Then use the correct way to get an element's style property : `getComputedStyle(element).filter`. If you wanted the authored one, you'd have had to use `element.getAttribute('style')

Comment: This seems like a bug to me. The standard syntax has the color last, Chrome shouldn't reorder it.

Comment: @Kaiido It does the same thing with `getComputedStyle`, except it changes `black` to `rgb(0, 0, 0)`. It still puts the color first instead of last.

Comment: The interesting thing is that if you put the color first in the html style attribute, both Firefox and Chrome will still render the shadow ok and running the sipped will give the result: Chrome will put color first, FF will reorder things and move color to the end

Comment: I think that getAttribute could be the way

Comment: @Barmar, the [specs for serializing CSS component values](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/#serialize-a-css-component-value), which should be used by `getComputedStyle()` ask to serialize `<color>` before `<length>`, so all UAs should return `drop-shadow(rgb(0, 0, 0) 0px 0px 5px)`.

Comment: Indeed getComputedStyle() provides more parseable values across browsers

Comment: @Kaiido Maybe I missed it, but I don't see where that document says the order; are you assuming that it's the order in the bullet list after "To serialize a CSS component value depends on the component"?  Also, where does it talk about components that are nested?

Comment: @Barmar, yes I am assuming the order of this swicth-list is the one that should be followed by the algo. Though I don't think there were any *"nested  components"* in CSS2 (which is unfortunately still the normative for DOM representation of CSSOM...). And thus implementations had to cover the new edge cases like list of function and *"nested components"* like `box-shadow`, but all do serialize these in this order.

Comment: @Kaiido I don't think that's how it's supposed to be interpreted. That list is just how to serialize *one* component. The order of the components comes from the earlier steps in the algorithm, where it says **For each CSS declaration declaration in trimmed list, invoke serialize a CSS value of declaration, and append the result to values.** So the order comes from the order of the declarations in the trimmed list.

Comment: @Barmar but `filter` is **one** component, an complicated one since it's actually a list of filter-functions, and that in this list, `drop-shadow` itself is composed of multiple values. In OP declarations list is `[filter, width, height, background]` *(where `background` is the only shorthand declaration)* In CSS2 there were no such functions, and the only *"nested component"*  I found is `text-shadow`, and both [dottoro](http://help.dottoro.com/ljgieemm.php) and MDN say that the order of Computed Values was `<color> x-off y-off blur`.

Comment: But I agree it's not completely clear, and that's why it would be time to redefine DOM specs to use CSS3 syntax... But anyway, chrome's behavior of splitting the declaration, reordering it in the serialization, but **without** serializing each splited  inner-value indeed looks like an bug. They should either return the authored full value, either serialize it completely (just like with `getComputedStyle`) but doing half of both looks wrong. And maybe opening an issue would clarify what is being done. But once again, using `element.style` to get the computed value of an element is a no-go.